# FileMaker layouts have missing elements. What could be the cause?

Tags: filemaker

I've recently started using filemaker to create some contact databases. I played around with one of the templates and after having tweaked the template to a point where its got all the data I need on it, I've found that I messed some things up in the process.

All the things listed below seem to have been affected.
'View Contact List Report' no longer works
'View Address Labels' no longer works
(Both show a prompt saying "no matching records were found")
the avery label printer doesn't show anything more than the name of each record.
(NB: All of these were working fine with the standard untouched template)

I'm guessing that because I altered the names of the fields, their corresponding scripts, calculations are no longer valid..

Where do I go to fix these scripts/calculations/etc (i.e. replace old field names with new ones..) is there any way I can edit the current ones or have a shot myself in the foot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you deleted some fields. If you simply renamed fields then the scripts should still work, unless you changed the data around drastically (perhaps the script is doing a find on a field that should contain some specific type which is no longer set in the field...) Go to layout mode, find out what script the button is calling and then open the script and re-set any set field steps that are calling missing fields and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker doesn't normally rely on names, so users are free to rename everything. It's possible to write code that does depend on names, but it must be an explicit decision and I'm not really sure they did this in templates.

But who knows; to check this figure out which scripts run these reports. To do this switch to the layout mode and double click the buttons (or right-click and select "Button" from the context menu). Open scripts, find the script there, and see if it does anything suspicious.